# Tree source code with modification

Tags: c++, tree

I'm looking for a tree implementation that has functionality that allows you to insert a child at a given location. Most trees out there, you can only do plain old insert, `Tree.insert(x)`, and depending on the tree type, it goes to a particular tree location.

I  seek code that supports something like `Tree.insert(node, x)`, which means to make `x` the direct child of `node`

IF anyone knows of a somewhat efficient tree source code (C++ or C) that doesn't use the STL and satifies the above, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't need the tree implementation to organise the nodes in any particular way, then there's nothing for the tree implementation to do. Just create a class with two child pointers and have at it.

Comment: That would be my last resort..

Comment: If the tree doesn't have its own way to tell where a child goes, I don't see how insert could work at all. How would it know how insert affects existing nodes?

Comment: Why do you need to avoid STL?

Comment: It's part of the specifications for an academic task.

Comment: I'm curious how you want to output your data without using the STL, dereferencing a null pointer and reading the core dump?

Comment: @jupp0r: Which part of the STL outputs data?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Seeing as “STL” is already an ill-defined colloquialism, I see no reason not to put iostream under the same umbrella.

Comment: @JonPurdy: Would you put the C Standard Library under it as well? jupp0r would, or he forgot about `printf`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Nope, good point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [`tree.hh`](http://tree.phi-sci.com), which provides an STL-like tree interface. There are `insert` and `append_child` member functions that accept an iterator and a value to insert, just as you describe. Unless you have very specialised needs, it’s almost certainly sufficient performancewise.

Comment: I think it includes <algorithm>. Doesn't that mean it's STL?

Comment: @CyberShot The example on the site happens to `#include <algorithm>`, but for no reason that I can see. What specifically is wrong with using the STL? The implementation does rely on the `<set>` container and `<queue>` adapter, as well as other standard headers; but again, why in the world would it matter? Standard headers exist to be relied upon.

Comment: It's part of the specifications for an academic task.

Comment: @CyberShot I’m sorry you have such absurd homework requirements. :(